# Gnuplot: how to make a histogram with only some bars stacked, others not?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, stackedbarseries, stacked-chart

Say I have data that I want to separate into different bars, but one of the is subdivided, as in. For instance:

```
A1 : 4
B1 : 1 2

A2 : 3
B2 : 2 3
```

And then I want to have (only) the B bars to be stacked. For the data above the graph should look like:

```
          y
o         y
o y     o y
o y     o x
o x     o x
A B     A B
```

How can I do that? I can change the format of the input file (or even use multiple files if necessary), but I really would like to have the final graph with clusters of bars, where some of the bars of each cluster are stacked, others not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possiblity how you can achieve that. For this you need to group the `A*` values together in the data file, followed by *two* new lines and then all `B*` values:

```
A1 4
A2 3


B1 1 2
B2 2 3
```

Separating the data sets with *two* new lines allows you to access them with the `index` statement. (Using two files would also work)

Then you plot the first histogram. This implicitely uses `0`, `1` etc as x-values, but gives them the labels `A1`, `A2`. For the `B*` values you create a new histogram with `newhistogram` and set its first x-value with `at` to `0` plus one `boxwidth`.

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
box_wd = 0.3
set boxwidth box_wd
set style fill solid
unset key

plot 'file.txt' using 2:xtic(1) index 0, \
     newhistogram at box_wd, \
     'file.txt' using 2:xtic(1) index 1,\
     '' using 3 index 1
```

With 4.6.4 you get:

[image]

The only thing might be, that the key of the two histograms are separated by a new line.